# Registering callback for Transparent Application Failover in Oracle jdbc driver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, ojdbc

In my app I create a connection by providing two DB server names in the db string url when creating the connection. Per my understanding, if the primary DB fails, connection will be established to the secondary (transparently).  Is this called Transparent Application Failover (TAF)?

Basically failover handled at the individual connection level, right?

How do I register a callback to get notified when failover occurs?

I am looking for specific API either at OracleDataSource level or OracleConnection level.  Can someone please provide few lines of sample code?.

DB version 12c, jdbc8 and oracle thin driver.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle the failover. Also, it depends on whether you want to handle only planned maintenance or unplanned outages. 
(a) You can use Universal Connection Pool (UCP) which takes care of both planned and unplanned outages. Checkout this [whitepaper](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf).
(b) If you want to build your own logic, then you can use [simplefan.jar](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html) to get notifications when the DB instance UP/DOWN events occur.

If you are looking for the API to register a TAF callback, here it is. Note that these are used with OCI and JDBC-OCI drivers only.

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection --
    public void registerTAFCallback(oracle.jdbc.OracleOCIFailover cbk, Object obj)
```